# Create a list with a value in it using only pure functions - python

Tags: python, functional-programming

Why this problem has no trivial solution is because I needs to be solved using only [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

Using only pure functions from Python's functional programming page (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#), how can one **create a list with a value in it?** If we'd like to create a list with a value in it, we'd (in code) just do

```py
x = [1]
```

I do not consider `[]` to be to be a part of the functions we're looking at here, since it has no signature and is not callable like any other function.

Using only functions to do this is not so trivial. One thought I had was to create a new list using `list()` and then append values to it. But `list().append` is mutable and does not return a new, or the, list with the item in it.

*What I really want to do is to turn `["a","b","c"]` into `[["a"],["b"],["c"]]`, with above constraints.*

Other proposals has been made like creating my own (pure) function doing what I want:

```py
def create_list(value) -> list:
    return [value]
```

and then just do `map(create_list, ["a","b","c"])` to get solution.
But this is a custom made function and is not from any of the python package functions (within https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html, as mentioned)

Comment: what's "not functional" about just setting `x = [1]`?

Comment: I don't understand why would one do that

Comment: `x = [1]` is functional, but I need to use pure functions. `[]` is no function

Comment: @DavidMeu yeah but that's just taking a tuple and converting to a list. Might as well take the list and convert it to inself `list([1])`.

Comment: Technically (1,) is not a function too, but syntactic sugar for creating a tuple

Comment: @RikardOlsson `[1]` counts as purely functional. It has no side effect. It creates an object and returns it. You can use a lambda expression like so `lambda *args: list(args)` but it does the exact same thing

Comment: Alright, maybe I need to be more clear of the requirements. If you were to generalize functions such that they have a name and arguments, it is hard to fit `[]` into that.

Comment: @RikardOlsson `def create_list(*args): return list(args)`. You can then use list(map(create_list, [1,2,3])) to get the result you wanted.

Comment: @Bharel True, but it bugs me that I need to create that function myself and that the built-in functions (plus all the other packages like itertools, functools and more) does not contain such that this is possible

Comment: @Bharel maybe MR is not approved beacuse of this

Comment: @RikardOlsson I'd imagine the reason there is no built-in function to do this is because Python tries to avoid "There's More Than One Way To Do It", and `[1]` is a perfectly fine way to do what you want, discounting the artificial constraint "it needs to be a function". If you need it to be a function, you will need to wrap it yourself.

Comment: A function that does mutation can still be considered pure. It's important that it does not mutate its input values, or does side-effects. But doing mutation do get a result, and then returning it. I consider it pure. It's more important how a function looks from the caller, not exactly how it is implemented.

Comment: @DavidRaab great to know. I guess it is being both pure and functional what I'm asking for? Or just functional. However, so far I cannot see a way of using functions from just https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html to construct `[[1],[2],[3]]` from `[1,2,3]`

Comment: @RikardOlsson IMHO you also could create a a list with `list()`, then call `append(x)` on it, and then return it. Yes, you mutate that list, but you can still consider it pure, as no input is mutated, and no side-effects are done. For example to sort an immutable List, The F# does convert it to a mutable array, does an in-place sort, and then convert it back to an immutable list. As long as no mutation leaks outside of an function, you can consider it pure.

Comment: @RikardOlsson But as an important aspect. Functional programming uses immutable data-structures. If you really want to learn more about functional programming, i think it helps to try to implement an immutable list by yourself. An immutable list only support two operation. 1) Add one element to the top. 2) Remove one element from the top. So basically, it is an immutable Stack. All other kind kind of operation like map, filter, redce, fold and so on are implemented on top of those two operations, and all of them return a new list.

Comment: @RikardOlsson Here you can see an example how to begin an immutable list in JavaScript. https://gist.github.com/DavidRaab/ed984650b7b716b97daa9f9925fa070c

Comment: @DavidRaab thanks for input. I found a solution to this problem and it is posted here if you want to check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does it using only functions from https://docs.python.org/3/library/functional.html

```py
import functools
import itertools

map(
    list, 
    map(
        functools.partial(
            itertools.repeat, 
            times=1,
        ), 
        [1,2,3]
    )
)
```

`functools.partial` creates a new function of `itertools.repeat` with "times" parameter set to 1. Each value in the list is then repeated once and turned into a new list using `list` function.

```
>>> [[1], [2], [3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Single element:

```
def to_list(elem):
    return list(range(elem, elem+1)))
```

To convert `[1,2,3]` into `[[1], [2], [3]]` with list comprehesion (it can be easily changed to `map`):

```
return [to_list(el) for el in input_list]
```

And without (ugly, but works ^^)

```
import itertools

def make_gen(elem):
    yield elem

def to_list(elem):
    return list(make_gen(elem))

def helper(elem, l):
    return list(itertools.chain(to_list(to_list(elem)), l))

def convert(l):
    if not l:
        return []
    return helper(l[0], convert(l[1:]))


print(convert([1, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: That one does solve it though. Smart! Do you know how to use same idea but to turn [1,2,3] into [[1], [2], [3]]? I'll update the question so my particular instance of the problem is

Comment: Can input list have arbitrary length? If so we probably need to use list comprehesion here, which you are against, am I right?

Comment: This is also great, and the `make_gen` here does what I cannot find any function within https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html do.. Why is it so??

Comment: You can - it's a generator, there is a section about them

Comment: No I have to define a function in code, which is a generator. I cannot use predefined functions from those sections to achieve that

Comment: Not sure do I understand your question - the code I provided has body of `make_gen` function

Answer (score 1):

```
lst=[1,2,3];
#this will print [[1],[2],[3]]
print(list(map(lambda x: [x],lst)));
```

Comment: You have the `[x]` in there, which is basically the essence of the problem

Comment: @RikardOlsson I don't see why this should be a problem. You also can create a list in such a way in functional languages like F# or Haskell.

Comment: I think I'm a bit unclear in my problem formulation. It's not a problem per say, but the question is how to achieve the same results using functions only from https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html. Your solution is using `lambda x: [x]` which is not defined in there

Answer (score 1):

To ensure non-mutability, you probably want to use tuples instead of lists (or be very disciplined with your lists).

Using a list comprehension would be a valid functional approach:

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [ [i] for i in A ]        # [[1], [2], [3]]
```

or with tuples:

```
A = (1,2,3)
B = tuple( (i,) for i in A )  # ((1,), (2,), (3,))
```

If you must use functions, then map() is probably a good solution to this:

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = list(map(lambda i:[i],A))
```

If even `[i]` is proscribed (but why would it be), you can use a a function to make a list directly from its arguments:

```
def makeList(*v): return list(*v)

A = makeList(1,2,3)
B = makeList(*map(makeList,A))

# combined
makeList(*map(makeList,makeList(1,2,3)))
```

*BTW functional programming is not about "only using functions",  it is more about non-mutability of results (and avoidance of side effects).  You may want to question whoever is sending you on this wild goose chase.*

Comment: 'return list(*v)' should be 'return list([*v])'?

Comment: @TomJ, no, `[*v]` does the same thing as `list(*v)`, using `list([*v])` would needlessly create a list and then make a new list out of its elements.

Comment: 'return list(*v)' should be 'return list(v)' to avoid the 'TypeError: list expected at most 1 argument, got 3'?

Answer (score 0):

> Using only pure functions from Python's functional programming page
> (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#), how can one create
> a list with a value in it? If we'd like to create a list with number 1
> in it

You might exploit generator as generator are described therein as follows

```
def justone():
    yield 1
lst = list(justone())
print(lst)
```

output

```
[1]
```

`justone` is function (which might be checked using [`inspect.isfunction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isfunction)) and is pure (as it does not alter anything outside)

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation you link, there are references to Iterators and Generators, which are powerful constructs present in Python (and other languages). You can consider a function to build a list as follows:

```
def list_from_args(*args):
    return [*args]
```

This is a (superfluous) wrapper around Iterator functionality. You can leverage the Iterator pattern in Python to accomplish a lot, whether that be creating/consuming objects (e.g. lists, tuples, dictionaries), or for processing data (e.g. reading/writing to a file line-by-line, paginating an API or DB Query, etc.)

The code above does the following, for example:

```
>>> example = list_from_args(1, 'a', 'ham', 'eggs', 44)
>>> example
[1, 'a', 'ham', 'eggs', 44]
```

The reason I labeled the above function as superfluous: Oftentimes, if you need to create a list on the fly, you can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).